If one column is not empty, require value in another column
I am seeking SharePoint List Formula that requires an entry in one column, if another column is not empty.
For example, I have a column titled "Approval Date". If an approval date is entered (column not empty), it is required that a value is entered in the "Total Budget Amount Approved" column.
Thank you in advance!

You will have to use List validation settings for your requirements.
Use list validation formula like:
=IF(ISBLANK([Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE))

OR:
=IF(ISBLANK([Approval Date]),TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK([Total Budget Amount Approved])))

Follow my answers given in below threads to add formula in List validation settings:

List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition
How to have validation for calculated column

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


Thank you! this worked. An additional add to this, I have it nested in an AND statement and am attempting to replicate the IF(ISBLANK criteria a total of 6 times (the list has multiple columns to input an approval date and total budget amount). The cumulative budget amount cannot exceed $1000, hence the AND statement. So far I have: =AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE))). When I add more, the validation results in an error. Any thoughts on how to correctly break this down?

Great, glad it worked for you. Can you please accept it as an Answer as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily? Thanks!

Please Ask a new question for your another query so that we can track it separately and other community contributors can also answer it. You can add URL of this post in your new question so that it will help to provide context for new question. Thanks!
